# CSS: How to make custom file upload button take full width (button works)

Tags: html, css, width, block, fixed-width

I am new to CSS and hope someone here can help me with this.

I am trying to apply a simple **custom style** to a **file upload button** (as part of an **HTML form**) to make it look similar to other buttons on my page and to get a similar look cross-browser.

So far I have the following which works as intended. 
My only problem now is that I would like the button to **take the full width of its parent div** (in my case this will span across 9/12 ('col-9') of the page).

I tried adding `width: 100%;` to the CSS but then the button doesn't work anymore.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="col-3 frmCaption">Attachments:</div>
<div class="col-9">
    <div class="customUpload btnUpload btnM">
        <span>Upload files</span>
        <input type="file" class="upload" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.btnDefault, .btnUpload {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}       
.btnDefault:focus, .btnDefault:hover, .btnUpload:focus, .btnUpload:hover {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
.btnM {
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
}
.customUpload {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.customUpload input.upload {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To style input elements, you need to actually style its `label` element.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label),

> The HTML Label Element () represents a caption for an item in a user interface. It can be **associated** with a control either by placing the control element inside the  element, or by using the for attribute. Such a control is called the labeled control of the label element.

So, whenever you click a `label`, the attached input gets triggered.

So, just wrap the input element in a label instead of a div and stretch as much as you want. That will fix your issue.

```css
.btnDefault,
.btnUpload {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  color: #333333;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.btnDefault:focus,
.btnDefault:hover,
.btnUpload:focus,
.btnUpload:hover {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
.btnM {
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
.customUpload {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.customUpload input.upload {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3 frmCaption">Attachments:</div>
<div class="col-9">
  <label class="customUpload btnUpload btnM"> <span>Upload files</span>

    <input type="file" class="upload" />
  </label>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/qt45fuqy/)**

Comment: Is the `label` really required? I was able to get it to work on the `div`. I'm I missing something?

Comment: @Rohit you are giving `width: 100%` explicity to both input and the wrapper, that is why it is working. but it is recommended to use label to style the inputs as you want. because it handles precisely. As you can see, in my case, I doesn't matter what is the width of the input.

Comment: Yes, You are right, I can't get it to work unless I have width on both button and its container. Thanks @Mr_Green

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - this is very helpful ! For now I will go with Rohit's suggestion but will test this later as well.

Comment: Update: after looking at your fiddle and testing your code I decided to go with this solution as I think this is the more professional approach and it works great (Rohit's suggestion is great too as he gave me exactly what I was looking for in the first place).

Comment: This is better approach to use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the width property to the containing `<div>` as well. Once the div has the full size, then only the button inside can have the full width.

For simplicity i have made change to html, you can move it to appropriate classes.

```
<div class="col-3 frmCaption">Attachments:</div>
<div class="col-9">
    <div class="customUpload btnUpload btnM" style="width:100%;">
        <span>Upload files</span>
        <input type="file" class="upload" style="width:100%;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nduskk2f/)

Or you can use this CSS andadd it both to your div and file upload,

```
.fullwidth
{
    width : 100%;
}

<div class="col-3 frmCaption">Attachments:</div>
<div class="col-9">
    <div class="customUpload btnUpload btnM fullwidth">
        <span>Upload files</span>
        <input type="file" class="upload fullwidth"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Update: after looking at Mr_Green's fiddle and testing his code I decided to go with his solution as I think this is the more professional approach and it works great (your suggestion is great too as he you me exactly what I was looking for in the first place). Thanks again !

Comment: Yes @Mr_Green has the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button take 12 cols (as you use a 12 col system) , as that is the max number of cils available, in that way the elemts will take up the size of the div that it is contained in